# DotNetNuke/.NET Ajax Redirect Issue

Tags: ajax, redirect, dotnetnuke, http-status-code-302

I'm working on a DotNetNuke site which has both a staging and production server. The issue right now is with a specific NB_Store menu, but I believe is actually an issue throughout the site.

On production, clicking the edit links in the product admin works fine. It appears that clicking the edit buttons sends an AJAX post request back to the site, which returns some redirect instructions, and then the browser redirects accordingly.

On the staging server however, instead of sending back redirect instructions, the redirect is handled as a 302 redirect, and the browser tries interpreting the entire redirected page as javascript. This stops me from actually getting to the page I need to go to!

The only differences between the two server I am aware of is we've updated the paths on stage to be a new domain (stage.xxx.com as opposed to the original www.xxx.com/subdir/dnn). I haven't tried using this admin menu in particular before so I don't know if changing the paths did it, or if it was already broken.

What can I try to fix this? I'm starting to run low on ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being an issue with application pool inheritance crap

Answer (score 0):

First, try to track the full request-reply sequence with Fiddler.
There may be intermediary redirects.

When you go to stage.xxx.com, what is the exact url that shows up in the browser?
If it is not just stage.xxx.com, but stage.xxx.com/Default.aspx?tabid=X, then something is causing a redirect.

I remember one case where there was a redirect from the site landing page to a particular page, instead of just defining this page as a home page in site settings. This caused mysterious AJAX request issues when all urls handled by ASP.NET (extensions .aspx, .ashx) except Default.aspx were redirected.

Comment: Fiddler shows the same redirect I got in Firebug, a 302 redirect

The weird thing is I've made a copy of the site and started making these changes, and essentially the *only* change to the site is the URL

it does stay at stage.xxx.com if I go there, no Default.aspx?etc

Comment: even if I point both paths to the same DNN instance and leave both portal aliases in place, the menu doesn't work on the stage.xxx.com, but still does work in the old path. nothing else is changing anywhere, but the redirect is being handled differently!